# Software Installation Licensing & Distribution Management System Recmmendation

Tags: version-control, installer

Can anyone recommend an existing management system solution (open source / commercial) for:

- Distributing desktop software installers (upgrades, notifications)
- Monitoring installations (hardware, version, license status)
- License management (granting, feature control based on license types)

Scenario:

- A building construction company has a list of engineering contractors who do modeling & drawing work.
- The building company has its in-house developed engineering software tools need to be distributed to those contractors.
- The company has to control the software versions and permissions.